# WFFM with v8.x - is FormID still required? Customized form views throw error without it

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, web-forms-for-marketers, sitecore-mvc

Using Sitecore 8.0 update 5 with WFFM build 150625 (aka Web Forms for Marketers 8.0 Update-4)

Adding the MVC form to my page using the experience editor results works as expected, however the FormID in presentation details is blank (the datasource is set).

Up till now I thought both were required to be set. Is FormId no longer required? or perhaps not required for the MVC form?

While this apparently works without the FormID being set, if I switch to a customized WFFM form [as documented by HedgeHog dev here](http://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2015/september/customizing%20wffm%20in%20sitecore%208.aspx) which also relies on the [Sitecore Marketplace MVC Areas module by BrainJocks](https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/S/Sitecore_MVC_Areas.aspx?sc_lang=en) the same blank FormID results in a 'No parameterless constructor defined for this object' YSOD

[image: No parameterless constructor defined for this object]

This error only occurs when the FormID is blank AND using a MVC WFFM Form *within an MVC Areas folder*. If I manually set the FormID it also works fine. If I use the same form definition with the standard 'MVC Form' rendering, it works with or without the FormID being set.

*What is the role of FormID and is it still required?*

*Should the FormID be set by the Insert wizard in Experience Editor?*

Comment: For a default install for WFFM/MVC, only the Datasource needs to be set. It may be that the code from the module is messing with something...

Comment: Could have sworn it was FormID that should be set and that Datasource needed to be set too but only because of a bug in earlier WFFM 2.3/2.4 versions, which has since been fixed.

Comment: @JimNoellsch - I pretty much thought the same. Confusing.

Comment: @JimNoellsch Maybe it has changed in Sitecore 8 then, but the Datasource needs to be set and there is a specific form selector when you select browse (or add the form via the Experience Editor) https://jammykam.wordpress.com/2015/10/05/webforms-for-marketers-allow-selection-of-existing-forms/

Comment: Bug raised, reference number 77782. Both datasource and FormID are apparently required. While it breaks my mvc wffm form within an MVC area, it's not clear what breaks using the standard mvc form with FormID missing, that standard scenario appears to work ok...